# Merging same date transaction in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sum, union

I have three tables...`tblLoanTaker`,`tblGiveLoan` and `tblReceiveLoan`...where `tblLoanTaker` table contains the people registered for the loan transaction, `tblGiveLoan` contains the transaction of the actions of Loan Given to a person and `tblReceiveLoan` contains the transaction of the actions of the Loan Received from a person in order to clear

The SQL Command that I have problem in displays the output at the bottom

```
    SELECT * FROM(  
    SELECT GL.EntryDate,SUM(GL.TotalAmount) as LoanGiven,0 as LoanReceived
    FROM tblGiveLoan as GL WHERE GL.UserId = @UserId and GL.LoanTakerId=@LoanTakerId
    GROUP BY GL.EntryDate   
    UNION ALL   
    SELECT RL.EntryDate,0 as LoanGiven,SUM(RL.Amount) as LoanReceived
    FROM tblReceiveLoan as RL WHERE RL.UserId = @UserId and RL.LoanTakerId=@LoanTakerId
    GROUP BY RL.EntryDate) as A 
    ORDER BY EntryDate ASC
```

```
EntryDate  LoanGiven                               LoanReceived
---------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
2020-12-03 0.00                                    1000.00
2020-12-03 11500.00                                0.00
2020-12-04 0.00                                    5000.00
2020-12-05 20000.00                                0.00
2020-12-06 0.00                                    1000.00
2020-12-07 0.00                                    500.00
2020-12-08 105.00                                  0.00
2020-12-09 250.00                                  0.00
2020-12-10 0.00                                    55.00
2020-12-22 0.00                                    500.00
```

How can I merge the row with the same date into one for example the first date of 3rd December 2020? I want the row to appear like this

```
EntryDate  LoanGiven                               LoanReceived
---------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
2020-12-03 11500.00                                1000.00
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please only tag a single RDBMS

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the aggregation in the outer query, not in the `union` members:

```
SELECT EntryDate, SUM(LoanGiven) AS LoanGiven, SUM(LoanReceived) AS LoanReceived
FROM(  
    SELECT EntryDate, TotalAmount as LoanGiven, 0 as LoanReceived
    FROM tblGiveLoan 
    WHERE UserId = @UserId and LoanTakerId = @LoanTakerId
    UNION ALL   
    SELECT EntryDate, 0, Amount
    FROM tblReceiveLoan
    WHERE UserId = @UserId and LoanTakerId = @LoanTakerId
) t
GROUP BY EntryDate
ORDER BY EntryDate
```

Note that prefixing the column names is not mandatory in the subquerires; each `UNION ALL` member has its own scope, so column names are unambiguous here.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this kept bugging me all afternoon, 
thank you so much